# Why can't I start using a recently installed package with Hombrew in macOS Catalina?

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew, macos-catalina, nvm

I've recently installed macOS Catalina and tried installing Homebrew + NVM but it seems I didn't do it correctly.

It seems that I installed NVM just fine

```sh
wayoshi@Uwu-MacBook-Pro ~ % brew list
nvm
```

But I cannot use the package:

```sh
wayoshi@Uwu-MacBook-Pro ~ % nvm install 12.21.0
zsh: command not found: nvm
```

I have this in my `~/.zshrc`

```sh
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

And this is what I get when I run `printf '%s\n' $path`

```
/Users/wayoshi/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/Users/wayoshi/bin
/usr/local/bin
/Users/wayoshi/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/Users/wayoshi/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

I guess this has something to do with env variables. Would you have any idea why this happened?

Comment: First: it might just be that zsh hasn't updated its list of known commands; try running `rehash` (to update the list), and then try `nvm` again. Second: if that doesn't do it, print your `PATH` with `printf '%s\n' $path` and edit the results into your question (note: this command is zsh-specific, and won't work in other shells).

Comment: `rehash` didn't do it 
I've posted my path on the question. Would you review?

Comment: Did you configure your bash/zsh profile to see nvm? See for instance https://jamesauble.medium.com/install-nvm-on-mac-with-brew-adb921fb92cc

Comment: Adding `export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh` to my `~/.zshrc` has solved it!

Comment: Yeah, baby! I gave it as answer too, in case this might help others.

Comment: lol, ok uwu....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say `brew info nvm` for instructions on how to configure your shell to see nvm. It sounds like you didn't follow those instructions:

```
You should create NVM's working directory if it doesn't exist:

  mkdir ~/.nvm

Add the following to /Users/<you>/.bash_profile or your desired shell
configuration file:

  export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
  [ -s "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && . "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
  [ -s "/usr/local/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && . "/usr/local/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```